# Background color and or text width doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have a block that's full width across the screen. Here, the text only needs to take 60% of the block.

My problem is that when I upload option 1, the background will show, but the text is not 60% but fullscreen.

If I upload option 2, there is no background color but the text is 60%.

What am i doing wrong?

```css
OPTION 1:

.tekst2 {
 margin-top: 25px;
 margin-bottom:25px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 60%;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    margin-top:25px;
    float:none;
}

.info
{
 margin-top: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 padding:50px;
 padding-bottom:50px;
 background-color: white;
    text-align:center;
}

OPTION 2:

.info
{
 margin-top: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 padding:50px;
 padding-bottom:50px;
 background-color: white;
    text-align:center;
}


.tekst2 {
 margin-top: 25px;
 margin-bottom:25px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 60%;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    margin-top:25px;
    float:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">

<div class="tekst1">
<h2 id="tekst1">This is some text</h2>
</div>
<div class="tekst2">
<span id="tekst2">Here is a lot of text and it doesnt scale to 60% when in option 1.</span>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML CODE**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <style>
  .info
  {
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    height:60%;
    padding:50px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
    background-color:white;
      text-align:center;
  }


  .tekst2 {
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      font-size:16px;
      margin-top:25px;
      float:none;
  }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: Add height to your div tags

Comment: What is the reason it DOES work with <style> in html, but not as CSS?

Comment: Are you properly linking the css file .It should work both way.

Comment: The css should work, cause i did everything else with it too. Its the order that makes the difference.

Comment: @JordySenssen to make the css work it has to be enclosed in <style> tags